# UITableView not working when adding JSON data

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to get a table view to load with some JSON data that I get from imgur. I can make a request to my backend that goes and gets the imgur data, spits it back out to me, and then I can populate the table. However, I get this really weird problem where the data is cutoff at the end. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yox0.jpg) is a picture. If I try and do another search it doesn't load any more data into the table, so clearly I break it when I am doing this. I don't really know what I'm doing wrong. I'm also trying to get this to be clickable with modals at some point, and dequeuing the reusable cell is probably not right either, but I guess I'll get there after this problem.

Anyway, any help would be appreciated.

```
class ViewController3: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

    var dataState: Data?

    var linkArray = [String]()
    var titleArray = [String]()

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    @IBOutlet weak var SearchTextField: UITextField!

    @IBAction func SearchButton(_ sender: Any) {

        let urlString = "http://localhost:3000/getimages"


        Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .post, parameters: ["search": SearchTextField.text!],encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON {
            response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                let json = JSON(response.data!)


                for (_, subJson) in json["data"] {
                    if let link = subJson["link"].string {
                       self.linkArray.append(link)
                    }
                    if let title = subJson["title"].string{
                        self.titleArray.append(title)
                    }
                }
                print("this is linkArray ", self.linkArray)
                print("this is titleArray ", self.titleArray)
                self.dataUpdated()
                break
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }


    }


    @IBAction func BackToTabControl(_ sender: Any) {
        let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        let tabBarVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBarController") as! UITabBarController

        if let vc1 = tabBarVC.viewControllers?.first as? ViewController1 {
            vc1.dataState = dataState
        }

        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = tabBarVC
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.bounces = true
        SearchTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done
        SearchTextField.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return titleArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellReuseIdentifier")! //1.

        let text = titleArray[indexPath.row] //2.

        cell.textLabel?.text = text //3.

        return cell //4.
    }

    func dataUpdated() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

}
```

Comment: Looks like an (Auto)Layout issue.

Comment: did u set constraint to prototype cell , do it first then run again , surely its autolayout issue

Comment: i am not a very smart man. how would i do this? In the constraint menu I see (http://imgur.com/a/GDsub) I do not see a place to set that constraint (ie prototype cell).

Answer (score 0):

Try next:

```
    if let label = cell.textLabel {
        label.text = text
        label.sizeToFit()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to click and hold within the tableview to get this to scroll in simulator.....apparently I did not know this. Thanks for the help guys.